# Creating a procedure or query for Postgresql where each times depends on the previous one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in Postgresql:

```
   item_id, item_timestamp, item_duration, item_some_condition
```

I want to calculate a list of periods and determine in which one "now()" happens to be? The calculation process is done as follows:

```
  a) if previous_item.item_some_condition is true:
    item_timestamp + item_duration 

  or

  b) if previous_item.item_some_condition is false:
    item_timestamp + item_duration + 10
```

As you can see, each item depends of the previous one. I want a high level advice of how to do that:

-- should it neccesarily be a function/procedure and not just a query?

-- because of "determine in which one "now()", I figure it must be

If so, should I first query all data from the table and store it in a variable? And then iterate over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(item_some_condition) over (partition by item_id order by item_timestamp) as prev_item_some_condition
      from t
     ) t
where now() >= item_timestamp and
      ( (now() < item_timestamp and prev_item_some_condition) or
        (now() < item_timestamp and prev_item_some_condition + interval '10 day')
      )
```

Comment: 1) so there's no need to do a calculation and store intermediate data? 2) also note that duration is a number of days, whereas item_timestamp is a date_and_time. will that still work?

Comment: @Kotaa . . . (1) no.  (2) I just used your syntax for adding ten, whatever that might be.